# Given $\|x\| \leq 1$ in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, show there exists a orthonormal sequence that converges weakly to $x$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Given $x\in H$ with $\| x\| \leq1$, show there exists an orthonormal sequence $(x_n)$ such that $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x$.

Below are my ideas and thoughts so far:

I thought about using the orthonormal basis to construct such sequence. But since we don't know if $H$ is countable, we can't assume there exists an orthonormal basis.

Also note that using Bessel's inequality, if we have an orthonormal sequence we have

$\sum_{n} |\langle x,x_n\rangle|^2 \leq \| x\|^2=1$.

So $\lim _{n \rightarrow\infty} \langle x,x_n\rangle^2 =0$.

Hence $\lim _{n \rightarrow\infty} \langle x,x_n\rangle =0$, which tells us $x_n$ converges weakly to zero.

But I'm not sure if this helps us with the question...

Any hints or ideas will be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Since $x$ is not arbitrary it does not follow that $x_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in your argument.

Comment: The claim is false. [Any infinite orthonormal sequence converges weakly to $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Weak_convergence_of_orthonormal_sequences). Hence if it happens to converge to some $x$ then $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible if $x=0$.

Suppose that $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x$ and is an orthonormal sequence.
Then you have already shown that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle x,x_n\rangle =0
$$
holds. From the weak convergence $x_n \rightharpoonup x$
we conclude
$$
\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle x,x_n\rangle =0.
$$
Therefore, $x=0$.

Constructing an orthonormal sequence $(x_n)$ which converges weakly to $0$ can be done in the usual way.

Comment: Are you saying that the statement is true if and only if $x=0$? Also, doesn't that mean $H$ is not necessarily infinite in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am saying the statement is true if and only if $x=0$. I was operating under the assumption that $H$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: May I ask where did you use that $H$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: For constructing an orthonormal sequence in the case of $x=0$. If $H$ is finite dimensional, then there cannot be an orthonormal sequence (because by definition a sequence is infinite and due to orthogonality their elements are linear independent).

Comment: @supinf Could you explain how one can construct an orthonormal sequence converging weakly to $0$?

Comment: @John Just pick one. Any orthonormal sequence converges to $0$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Weak_convergence_of_orthonormal_sequences